# Generating SALT for Android Licensing

Tags: android, salt, android-lvl

I would like to implement licensing in my app and need some help here.

The sample app has this:

```
// REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN SALT , THIS IS FROM EXAMPLE
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[]{
            -46, 65, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64,
            89
    };
```

I would like to know do I just change the numbers to some random number or do I have to generate it using `SecureRandom`?

I came across [this code](http://coltsoftware.blogspot.com/2013/03/java-salt-shaker.html), do I have to set the SALT variable from the clipboard?

Also, does SALT have to be different for every device or same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non random salt isn't going to be very secure, in theory someone can generate every combo for your app (however thats unlikely).

I suggest you take a look RSA public key cryptography. You may want to have a look at [How to use public encryption to manage licensing on android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722841/how-to-use-public-encryption-to-manage-licensing-on-android-applications) .

Edit: I was a bit unclear on you question at first, [Android: Do the random SALT bytes passed to AESObfuscator need to stay the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858454/android-do-the-random-salt-bytes-passed-to-aesobfuscator-need-to-stay-the-same) i think is a duplicate that has an answer.

Comment: I'm new to this, so please bear with me. Do I have generate the SALT every time the app runs? Or do I have to generate it just once and then store it in the SALT variable?

Comment: I don't know enough about what your trying to do to answer that. Honestly, if you doing licensing, you really should read http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html . If you read the links on the other answers they also give you more information which should help you get your footing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any 20 randomly generated bytes
I think you can use the following Generator for this purpose:

http://www.random.org/integers/?num=20&min=0&max=255&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new